# Angular directive - need to access required controller from directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm writing an angular "tab" directive which needs to communicate with a parent "tabs" directive by sending a reference to itself to the parent.

I am trying to keep my code in the directive's controller, not the link function, because I'm not really doing anything with DOM.

The problem is that if i use {require: '^tabs'} i can get a copy of the required directive's controller like this..

```
link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrls) {
    var controller = ctrls[0];
}
```

but how would I do this inside the directive's controller function?

Comment: I believe you have to do this in the link, as the controller lookup done by require searched the DOM for directives and their respective controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always a fun problem for me. I like to think that I am playing on the wild side with my solution to this common case.

First, I take a step back to the controllerAs view syntax as suggested in the the angular style guide (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controlleras-controller-syntax)

Using this syntax you can define your directive as:

```
    var directive = {
        require: '^myParentDirective',
        restrict: 'EA',
        controller: 'MyController as myCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'super/awesome/app/my/my.directive.html',
        scope: {
            myProp: '='
        }, // isolate scope
        link: link
    };

    function link(scope, element, attr, myParentCtrl) {

        scope.myCtrl.myParent = myParentCtrl;

    }
```

The catch (there's always a catch):

Remember that a directive's controller is constructed before the link function is invoked. So you cannot expect the myParent property to be resolved in the code executed during the controller's construction.

```
function MyController($scope) {

    var _self = this;

    _self.myParent.register(_self); // myParent is not defined

}
```

Instead wait until you are sure myParent is resolved

```
function MyController(scope) {

    var _self = this;

    _self.initialize = initialize;

    return;

    function initialize() {

        _self.myParent.register(_self); // myParent might be defined

    }

}
```

then do something like

```
function link(scope, element, attr, myParentCtrl) {

    scope.myCtrl.myParent = myParentCtrl;

    scope.myCtrl.initialize();

}
```

Let me know if this helps, is off base, or if you need more clarification.

(Also, please excuse syntax errors)

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am trying to do. The only difference is that I need to pass $scope in the register method, not _self becuse the parent directory need access to scope methods and $destroy etc. Unless I have misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you need to share data between controllers, you can create a factory/service to store the data, and inject the service in those controllers. The data set in the service will be singleton.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .factory('myService', function() {
    var myData;
    return {
      getData: function () {
        return this.myData;
      },
      setData: function (data) {
        this.myData = data;
      }
    }
  .controller('controller1', function(myService) {
  })
  .controller('controller2', function(myService) {
  })
});
```

If the child directive has no scope data, you can also set the directive scope to false and it will inherit the scope of the parent controller.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    controller: 'controller1'
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks dannielum, but for my current problem I don't think a singleton would work.